# Run code at startup of an Erlang Application

Tags: erlang, startup

I would like to run some code at the startup of an Erlang Application. Is's about to connect to the Database and initialise some things. How can i do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call the desired functions from the `start/2` function of your application's entry module (which implements `-behaviour(application)` in it and is specified in your `*.app` or `*.app.src` if you use rebar).
After you create a release, the `start/2` function will be executed when starting the application.

More information about making a release can be found [here](https://github.com/rebar/rebar/wiki/Release-handling) (assuming `rebar` is used).